# Where is the moodle documentation for using Core web service functions that indicates the parameter required

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I can not see the documentation telling what are the related parameters to their Core web service functions.

Moodle has a lot of Core web service functions listed at
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

but the required/optional parameter and/or how to use the function is not indicated.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in the Moodle docs: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services#Developer_documentation

You can enable documentation for your site at:
Site admin > Plugins > Web services > Manage protocols > Web services documentation

You can then view that documentation at:
Site admin > Plugins > Web services > API Documentation

This page lists all the required + optional params for each of the web service functions available on your site (including any from 3rd-party plugins you may have installed), as well as the expected response.